# How a derived class cannot resolved members of its base class at compile time?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

Consider this code:

```
class X { public: int i; }; 
class A : public virtual X   { public: int j; }; 
class B : public virtual X   { public: double d; }; 
class C : public A, public B { public: int k; }; 
// cannot resolve location of pa->X::i at compile-time 
void foo( const A* pa ) { pa->i = 1024; } 

main() { 
   foo( new A ); 
   foo( new C ); 
   // ... 
}
```

In the book "**Inside C++ object model**", it is said that:

> the compiler cannot fix the physical offset of `X::i` accessed through
>   `pa` within `foo()`, since the actual type of `pa` can vary with each of
>   `foo()'s` invocations.

So, the compiler has to create something like this:

```
// possible compiler transformation 
void foo( const A* pa ) { pa->__vbcX->i = 1024; }
```

If the program has a pointer to the virtual base class, how can't it resolve the memory address of that member at compile time? As far as I know, when each derived class object is created, the memory layout of each object consists of:

- all members in the base class
- a virtual pointer (of a virtual destructor)
- a pointer to the virtual base class of the derived object
- all of the members of the derived class object.

So, finding the base class member should simply be finding the right offset from the starting address of the derived class object. But why can't it be resolved?

Answer (score 1):

The point is that the base class `X` is *virtual* with respect to `A`, so  `A` doesn't yet know who the *actual* base class will be. The actual base subobject will only be determined by the ultimate derived object, `C` in this case. In other words, the actual base subobject depends on the dynamic type of `*p` and cannot be decided statically.

Imagine you had another `class C2 : A, B, A2, B2`, where `A2` and `B2` are similar. You could also call `foo` with a pointer to a `C2`, and now the base `X` might be somewhere else.

Comment: I thought that virtual class is for sharing the same base class subobject: `http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/118-virtual-base-classes/` , and is constructed first in the inheritance tree. If according to the article, I think the memory layout of class `C` will be a contiguous region consist of memory layout of X + A + B + C, and in the case of A is X + A. How can it has problem finding the member of base?